# OpenCV C++ Drawing and Analyzing Line

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on a OpenCV program capable of detecting Boxers punches and categories them. At the moment my program goes through all the different image processing, finds and detects contours, draws bounding boxes on ROI's (Region Of Interest), I am also computing some properties of each bounding box such as: Area and Center Point.

Now what i want to do is to draw a line from each bounding box starting from the center point and analyze that line for its Angle and Length. Have a look at the Image that illustrates my aim:

[image]

So hopefully now you guys have a better overview........

My Question here is How do i draw such line from starting position to end position store it in a vector to analyse it...?

I did some research on various functions that draw lines but non of them seem to be appropriate for my purpose. Here are some Research links:

[Opencv Draw Line & Line iterator & poly lines](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line)

Also looked at arcLength, fitLine, clipLine & Hough transform

Could some one indicate me which technique would best fit my aim...?
Some good read, examples, Or just suggest how to even start this whole thing

Regards Hopefully my problem is well understood by now

Comment: do you need to connect the red center of the upper bounding box with the corresponding red center of the lower bounding box?

Comment: yes the top points are possible movements in a video sequence, bottom points represent starting position and top center points represent the end of the gesture. I want to connect these analyse the angle and length of the line to distinguished possible gesture

Answer (score 2):

Store the **centroid** positions frame-by-frame of an object being tracked in an array, then feed it to the PolyLines() function.

Comment: ok thx for your answer: I am already storing the center position in ever frame I am using this algorithm to calculate and store it in a Point variable, Also this is within a infinite loop,  `Point center = Point(oko[0].x + (oko[0].width/2), oko[0].y + (oko[0].height/2));
    cout<<"Center Point of Box: 0 is: " <<center<<endl;
    circle(drawing, center, 3, Scalar(255,255,255), CV_FILLED);`

Comment: Now i looked up polylines [here]http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html     But now I am not to sure how to use this function.....could you suggest some decent read or provide some examples....?

Answer (score 0):

We can use PolyLines as following:

```
polylines(img  /*image where to plot*/, &points /*the points (centroids in your case)*/ ,&numPoint /*number of points*/,1,false /*contour is not closed shape*/, Scalar(255,255,255),3, CV_AA, 0);
```

-Pay attention that points must be defined as Mat